# How to publish a book having TIER4?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

I have read the documents stating which types of work are available for the students, studying in the UK and having TIER4 visa. These state that you can't be self employed. Another site suggests that being self-employed means to sell goods or services, not being registered as a company. If I have written a book and I want to publish it, this excludes Kindle Direct Publishing. If I sign a contract with a Publisher, does it mean, that I sell good, i. e. manuscript and considered again to be self-employed?

Comment: Have you considered publishing the book in your country of origin?

Comment: @Viktor even if I publish it or become employed in my country of origin TIER4 still has an impact

Comment: @Viktor what I want to know, what is actually a contract between me and publisher and how do I sell my IP without violating the law