# Are UK Tier 4 visa holders permitted to have royalty income?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, visa

I am going to the UK for an MA degree. According to the Tier-4 rules, I am not allowed to work more than 20 hours per week or be self-employed.

I currently have a published book, and I receive royalty income from it. The book was published in my home country prior to my obtaining a Tier-4 visa. Am I allowed to continue to receive such royalty income from my previous work while studying in the UK? Or would this be considered to be self-employment? I have sufficient savings to fund my time living in the UK without factoring in future royalty income.

A similar question was asked: [How to publish a book having TIER4?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/how-to-publish-a-book-having-tier4), however this discusses publication of a book while on the visa, rather than publication before obtaining the visa.

Comment: I can't answer your question but I thought you might like to know the jargon for such income is "non-employment income". Income from rent is another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to have additional income, royalty or whatever.

If this income is less than personal allowance, $7000 (in 2014, when I were there), you don't have to do anything. If your earn more than that, you need to pay tax.

As long as you don't "work more than 20 hours per week or be self-employed", you would be fine.

In the UK, you don't file tax return, so if the income goes into your bank account in your home country, I guess it is not relevant.